# Bot - DisTubeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Expected 'Discord.Message'

Tags: discord.js, bots, distube

I made a music bot, but I'm looking to turn this into interactions, but I'm having a problem calling the play function.

With "message" it works, but with "interaction" it doesn't. I tried to pass on some information, I searched but I couldn't.

I even found a different way, but it didn't work.

The error returned is this:

`DisTubeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Expected 'Discord.Message' for 'message', but got undefined (undefined)`

Play.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .setDescription('Play a song!')
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('song').setDescription('Enter name of the music.')),

  async execute (interaction, client){
    // if(!interaction.member.voice.channel) return interaction.reply("Please, join a voice channel!");

    const music = interaction.options.getString('song');
    if(!music) return interaction.reply("Please, provide a song!");
    
    await client.distube.play(interaction, music);

    // await client.distube.playVoiceChannel(
    //   interaction.member.voice.channel,
    //   music,
    //   { 
    //     textChannel: interaction.channel,
    //     member: interaction.member
    //   }
    // );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DisTube, at the time of this question being posted, doesn't support slash commands, and [it looks like the creator doesn't have any plans on supporting it officially](https://github.com/skick1234/DisTube/issues/78#issuecomment-825392557). As a workaround, you can use the `Distube#playVoiceChannel` method instead of the `Distube#play` method, like so:

```js
await client.distube.playVoiceChannel(interaction.member.voice.channel, music);
```

But before you do any of that, it looks like `interaction` is undefined - that's probably a problem with your command handler, so look there.

Edit: Also [docs](https://distube.js.org/#/docs/DisTube/stable/class/DisTube?scrollTo=playVoiceChannel) for `Distube#playVoiceChannel` if you're interested